# How call an Intent switch from a c2dm message reciever

Tags: android

I have a simple c2dm message receiver class which is called whenever the device receives a c2dm message.  In one case, I want to have the message receiver class perform an intent switch to load a different activity. Android throws an exception when this happens

```
01-07 02:28:52.480: E/AndroidRuntime(440): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

I guess I could investigate this flag suggested in the exception, but i'm wondering if maybe i'm taking the wrong approach and there is a better way to do this?

c2dm message receiver class:

```
public class C2DMMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.w("C2DM", "Message Receiver called");
                if ("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE".equals(action)) {
                    Log.w("C2DM", "Received message");
                    final String payload = intent.getStringExtra("payload");
                    Log.d("C2DM", "dmControl: payload = " + payload);

                    // Message handling
                    if(payload.equals("RdyRoom::join")) {
                        Intent rIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), ReadyRoomActivity.class);
                        context.startActivity(rIntent);
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: I would recommend reading about the flag.  It is in the Intent docs.  However, could you provide more information about what you are trying to accomplish?  Is the user in an Activity and is waiting for this response?  What happens before and what do you want to happen after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your intent

```
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```